# Yii2 RBAC: как удалить роль?

Tags: yii2, rbac

Использую эту инструкцию для настройки - [инструкция](http://developer.uz/blog/rbac-%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B2-yii2/)

Но не могу как понять - как удалить роль? Если я создал ошибочно роль

Comment: Роль - это запись в БД. Удалить запись = удалить роль. Возможно есть смысл в изменении роли.

Answer (score 2):

Можно методом **remove** класса yii\rbac\DbManager

```
$role = Yii::$app->authManager->getRole("admin");
Yii::$app->authManager->remove($role);
```

Источник [документация](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-rbac-dbmanager)